# How to fix git conflicts with npm autogenerated files?

Tags: laravel, git

Making git pull I got conflict errors:

```
user@os:/proects/path$ clear
user@os:/proects/path$ git pull origin frontend-4
Password for 'https://usrename@github.com':
From https://github.com/clientname/project
 * branch            frontend-4 -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        package.json
        public/js/app.js
        public/mix-manifest.json
        resources/js/components/common/Header.vue
        resources/js/routes.js
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
user@os:/proects/path$ git stash
```

Saved working directory and index state WIP on main: e214191 Gigs pictures

```
making git stash I got conflicts with npm autogenerated files :
user@os:/proects/path$ git pull origin frontend-4
Password for 'https://usrename@github.com':
From https://github.com/clientname/project
 * branch            frontend-4 -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging resources/js/routes.js
Auto-merging resources/js/components/common/Header.vue
Auto-merging public/js/app.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/js/app.js
Auto-merging public/css/frontend.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in public/css/frontend.css
Auto-merging package.json
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I tried to remove them first and run

```
npm run watch-poll
```

next
but  I got errors :

```
user@os:/proects/path$ rm public/js/app.js
user@os:/proects/path$ rm public/css/frontend.css
user@os:/proects/path$ git commit -m "ignore compiled asset"
U       public/css/frontend.css
U       public/js/app.js
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

How can it be fixed ?

I do not need decision like setting in .gitignore rules:

```
/public/js/*
/public/css/*
```

as I need to upload my css/files to server, as I do not have npm installed on server.

Comment: You have two choices, really: (1) don't store generated files; (2) resolve conflicts in the stored, generated files. You chose #2. Resolve the conflicts.

Comment: But How to Resolve it? Manually in editor? I expected rm commands would help me...

Comment: The same way you resolve any conflict: you pick out or build up the correct final result, use `git add` to tell Git *this is the correct final result*, and run `git <operation> --continue` (insert whatever the operation is) to continue on. How you pick the correct final result is up to you. You're the one who chose to store the autogenerated files in the first place.

Comment: Could you please propose any practical decision? Lets remenber that autigenerated public/js/app.js has several Mib in size...

Comment: The *most* practical way to do this is not to store the autogenerated files. Don't use Git as a release tool; it isn't one and is poor at playing one. Failing that, read up on how `git merge` works: for all the autogenerated files, you want "one side", and you want to *remove* any files from the "other side".

Comment: Incidentally, a google search for "laravel deployment" turns up [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment), which describes how to do it. I don't think it involves storing the generated npm output in a Git repository...

Answer (score 0):

**Answer : Find lines that prevent auto merging and then do rest**

The main problem for not commiting or pushing is because of the conflicts between files

> Git can handle most merges on its own with automatic merging features. A conflict arises when two separate branches have made edits to the same line in a file, or when a file has been deleted in one branch but edited in the other

There are many tools to help resolve merge conflicts, such as :

1. git log
2. git reset
3. git status
4. git checkout
5. git reset

#**How to identify merge conflicts**

As we have experienced from the proceeding example, Git will produce some descriptive output letting us know that a CONFLICT has occcured. We can gain further insight by running the git status command

```
$ git status
On branch main
You have unmerged paths.
(fix conflicts and run "git commit")
(use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

both modified:   merge.txt
```

**The output from git status indicates that there are unmerged paths due to a conflict.** The merge.text file now appears in a modified state. Let's examine the file and see whats modified.

```
$ cat merge.txt
<<<<<<< HEAD
this is some content to mess with
content to append
=======
totally different content to merge later
>>>>>>> new_branch_to_merge_later
```

Here we have used the cat command to put out the contents of the merge.txt file. We can see some strange new additions

Think of these new lines as "conflict dividers". The ======= line is the "center" of the conflict. All the content between the center and the <<<<<<< HEAD line is content that exists in the current branch main which the HEAD ref is pointing to. Alternatively all content between the center and >>>>>>> new_branch_to_merge_later is content that is present in our merging branch.

#**How to resolve merge conflicts using the command line**

The most direct way to resolve a merge conflict is to edit the conflicted file. Open the merge.txt file in your favorite editor. For our example lets simply remove all the conflict dividers. The modified merge.txt content should then look like:

```
this is some content to mess with
content to append
totally different content to merge later
```

Once the file has been edited use git add merge.txt to stage the new merged content. To finalize the merge create a new commit by executing:

```
git commit -m "merged and resolved the conflict in merge.txt"
```

Git will see that the conflict has been resolved and creates a new merge commit to finalize the merge.

#***Git commands that can help resolve merge conflicts***

**General tools**

```
git status
```

The status command is in frequent use when a working with Git and during a merge it will help identify conflicted files.

```
git log --merge
```

Passing the --merge argument to the git log command will produce a log with a list of commits that conflict between the merging branches.

```
git diff
```

diff helps find differences between states of a repository/files. This is useful in predicting and preventing merge conflicts.

**Tools for when git fails to start a merge**

```
git checkout
```

checkout can be used for undoing changes to files, or for changing branches

```
git reset --mixed
```

reset can be used to undo changes to the working directory and staging area.

Tools for when git conflicts arise during a merge

```
git merge --abort
```

Executing git merge with the --abort option will exit from the merge process and return the branch to the state before the merge began.

```
git reset
```

Git reset can be used during a merge conflict to reset conflicted files to a know good state